# What is the maximum number of users in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

What is the maximum number of users on a single database that one can define?

I cannot seem to find this information on [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any hard limit; the users for a database can be viewed through the sys.database_principals view which has an int principal_id which I'll assume is unique... so around 2 billion theoretically.

Answer (score 3):

There is no defined max number of logins and users in SQL Server. Although, based on how your application is configured you can hit the max number of user connections you can have to a given database (32,767) rather quickly.